# jQuery ignore HTML5 input required

Tags: jquery, html, required

I have a HTML input

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       name="inputExtraEmail" 
       id="extraEpost" 
       placeholder="E-post" 
       required/>
```

I want to ignore the `required` property in a jQuery click method

```
$('#addBtn').click(function (e) {

}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can't you remove the required tag, or is this needed for something else?

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to remove required attribute attach it at the last statement

```
  $('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
        $('#extraEpost').removeAttr('required');

           //your code


        $('#extraEpost').attr('required',true);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**:

```
$('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
    $('#extraEpost').removeAttr('required');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
    $('#extraEpost').removeAttr('required');
});
```

or just add novalidate attribute as below

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

```
$('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
        $('#extraEpost').attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');    
});
```